# How to write a Procedure which exports Oracle database table data into excel file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
set feedback off
set heading off
set underline off

set colsep ','

spool /u01/app/oracle/export/mysheet.csv

select * from mytab'
spool off
```

This works fine on command prompt but I need to write a procedure for the same, can anyone help

Comment: save it as a file and run it from sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [this package](http://www.oracle-developer.net/content/utilities/data_dump.sql) from oracle-developer.net in a production database and it has worked flawlessly.  It works on Oracle 8i onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use the results from your SQL and then use the PL/SQL package UTL_FILE to open and write to a file, separating your results with commas in a variable first.

As an example:

`vline` would contain the results from your SELECT with each column separated by a comma as in `SELECT col1 ||','|| col2 ||',||` ... `INTO vline` ...

`vfile` is the name of your file.

```
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(vfile, vline));
```

Search Oracle docs for more info on the UTL_FILE package.

HTH